# TSLint count errors

Tags: tslint

How to count TSLint errors?

I am working in a project with Angular where we changed the TSLint rules and we have massive output.

I would like to count the issues to see over the time if we progressively decrease them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command worked for me on Mac:

```
tslint 'src/**/*.ts' | wc -l
```

Output:
 1953 errors.